# SAS Code Efficiency

Tags: sql, sas

Could someone please help me with how SAS/SQL processes nested queries or subqueries. Would it do the inner select, "select sum(price) from MasterFile" only once or with each iteration of the outer query?

```
proc sql; 
create table categorySpend as 
select categoryid, sum (price) as CategoryRevenue, (select sum(price) from MasterFile)as TotalRevenue 
from MasterFile 
group by categoryid; 
quit;
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably the best way to get an idea of what's going on behind the scenes is to use the undocumented `_method` and `_tree` options in the `proc sql` statement. For a very detailed write-up, this is a good source:

http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/101-30.pdf